# On button click values in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my Ajax call I want to pass two parameters which I get on button click:

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var name = $(this).data("name");

    e.preventDefault();

    process.forEach(performStep);
});
```

This proccess is an array I am looping trough to preform a call in forEach:

```
var process = [
    {
        "url" : "/api/first/call",
        "text" : "First call "
},
    {
        "url" : "/api/second/call",
        "text" : "Second call "
}
];
```

And finally Ajax code:

```
function performStep(value, index, array)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: value.url,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'id': id,
            'name': name
        }),
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json-patch+json',
    success: function () {
       
        }
    },
        error: function (xhr) {
            
        }
    });
}
```

When I am putting it in function arguments it won't catch them. How can I pass it in performStep() function? I am returning them when I `console.log()` the on click .button() class.

Tried to add them in *process.forEach(performStep);* but it won't work. I am pretty new with JS, Ajax and jQuery, so maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144210/pass-a-variable-to-foreach-function I believe that is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that you're passing `performStep` to `forEach()` by *reference*. This means that the parameters which `forEach()` passes to the handler function (`currentValue`, `index` and `array`) are provided as arguments. However your function appears to be expecting the `id` and `name` values from the outer scope.

To pass the `id` and `name` values you need to include them as arguments within both the function call and definition:

```js
var process = [{
  "url": "/api/first/call",
  "text": "First call "
}, {
  "url": "/api/second/call",
  "text": "Second call "
}];

$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  var name = $(this).data("name");

  e.preventDefault();

  process.forEach(function(obj) {
    performStep(obj, id, name);
  });
});

function performStep(value, id, name) {
  console.log(value);
  console.log(id);
  console.log(name);
  
  // ajax request...
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" data-id="foo" data-name="bar">Click me</button>
<button class="button" data-id="fizz" data-name="buzz">Click me</button>
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks a lot. @RoryMcCrossan